# Parity of number of divisors

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, proof-techniques

Im pretty new here.

My question showing me an algorithm:

TRUE_SEQ(A[1...n])

```
for i <- 1 to n do
 A[i] <- FALSE
for i <- 1 to n do 
 k <- i
 while(k <= n) do
  FLIP(A[k])
  k <- k + i
```

FLIP(x)

```
if x = TRUE then
 x <- FALSE
else
 x <- TRUE
```

Now i need to prove that after we finish TRUE_SEQ, the value of $A[i]$ is TRUE if and only if $i \in N$ is a power of a some natural number.

We learned about loop recorded sequence (Im not sure if i say it correctly in english)

Any way i would like a hint (and prefer a hint than a solution - as those are my homeworks)

Thank you for the help.

Comment: The question does not make sense. Every number $i\in \mathbb{N}$ is a power of a natural number, namely $i^1$. And $4=2^2$ will be A[4]=true but $8=2^3$ will be A[8]=false.

Comment: power of a natural number, eg, 3 is not a power of any natural number, because there is not an $x \in N$ such that $3 = x^2$

Comment: Welcome. Can you rename your title to something more specific? That will help people understand your question better.

Comment: I dont have an idea for something more specific, i know its pretty general, but i dont have an idea for specificity. Thanks

Comment: Next time, I suggest running the algorithm and seeing what the output is. This is how you would discover that the TRUE positions correspond to squares.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the algorithm, the value of $A[n]$ is the parity of the number of divisors of $n$ (TRUE means odd parity). The divisors of $n$ come in pairs $i,n/i$. Most of these pairs consist of two distinct values, but if $n$ is a square, then when $i = \sqrt{n}$, both elements are equal. This shows that $A[n]$ is TRUE if and only if $n$ is a square.